# How to handle multiple text fields effectively in UITextField's shouldChangeCharactersIn

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I've a number of textFields, I want to change text colour to white when user is typing them in text field. Following is my code with a lot of if conditions which doesn't seem to be efficient. Is there any way to do it without writing a lot of if conditions?

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if textField == emailTextField {
        emailTextField.textColor = .white
    } else if textField == nameTextField {
        nameTextField.textColor = .white
    } else if textField == addressTextField {
        addressTextField.textColor = .white
    }

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do

```
textField.textColor = .white
```

and whatever the `textfield` is it's `textColor` will be changed